# If Else and Exception in JForm

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch, jtextfield, jform

I am trying to throw the exception when the user enters other integer than 1 and 2 into the jtextfield,

```
public class SearchEmployee extends javax.swing.JFrame  {

    /**
     * Creates new form SearchEmployee
     */
    public SearchEmployee() {
        
        initComponents();

    }
     // A utility function to check
    // whether a code is valid or not
       public static boolean isCodeValid(String id)
        throws IdNotFoundException
    {
        if(!id.equals("1")){
            throw new IdNotFoundException();
        }else if(!id.equals("2")){
            throw new IdNotFoundException();
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and supposedly after users clicked the search button, they are supposedly going to the new page where employee details will be displayed.

```
 private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String id = staffID.getText();

        try{
            if(isCodeValid("1")){
                EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
                emp.name.setText("Sky Peach");
                emp.email.setText("skypeach@gmail.com");
                emp.address.setText("Pangsapuri Sri Puteri");
                emp.phoneNo.setText("1999999999");
                emp.department.setText("IT");
                emp.designation.setText("Software Developer");
                emp.show();
            }else if(isCodeValid("2")){
                EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
                emp.name.setText("Sky Orange");
                emp.email.setText("skyorange@gmail.com");
                emp.address.setText("Pangsapuri Sri Puteri");
                emp.phoneNo.setText("2999999999");
                emp.department.setText("IT");
                emp.designation.setText("Software Engineer");
                emp.show();
            }
        }catch (IdNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
            }
        
        
        
  
    }
```

however, the exception was thrown even when i entered the integer 1 and 2. How to fix this error?

Comment: You should use `&&` to combine the conditional statements, since `"1" != "2"` the first will throw an exception for `"2"`, and the second will throw an exception for `"1"`. Also, rather than throwing an exception, you could simply return `false` and handle it appropriately, which would reduce your entire method to `return id.equals("1") || id.equals("2");`

Comment: `public static boolean isCodeValid(String id) { return id.matches("[12]"); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rogue and DevilsHnd answer in the comments, I would suggest to switch the arguments used for the string comparison. This avoids NPEs when the id parameter is null.

```
public static boolean isCodeValid(String id) { return "1".equals(id) || "2".equals(id); }
```

Or make an excplicit null check (defensive programming) before. The approach with the regex is simpler to expand

```
public static boolean isCodeValid(String id) { 
    Objects.requireNonNull(id);
    return id.matches("[12]"); 
}
```

Comment: I understand the appeal of `"literal".equals(arg)`, but over the years I've seen more issues (with readability and bugs) that resulted from a situation where a parameter should _not_ have been null, and the original way of calling `arg.equals("literal")` would have saved the headache / pointed it out quicker.